# TaskExecutor and TaskScheduler being picked up by Spring as same type

Tags: java, spring

I have the following configuration:

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class MyConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {

        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(10);
        return scheduler;
    }

}
```

Then I have a class listening for ContextRefreshEvents, like:

```
@Component
public class ScreenerScheduler implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Inject
    private TaskScheduler scheduler;

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
}
```

When I run the application (web) I get:

```
Error creating bean with name 'screenerJobExecutor':
  Injection of autowired dependencies  failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
  Could not autowire field:
  private org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor example.workflow.ScreenerJobExecutor.executor;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:
  No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor] is defined:
  expected single matching bean but found 2: taskExecutor,taskScheduler
```

Anyone could help figuring out why spring see two possible types for a TaskScheuler?

Comment: I'm injecting TaskExecutor and TaskSceduler,and both are different interfaces without any hierarchical relationship.... Using @Qualifier fixes it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This `@Bean` method

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
```

returns an object of type `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` which is

```
public class ThreadPoolTaskScheduler extends ExecutorConfigurationSupport
    implements TaskScheduler, SchedulingTaskExecutor {
```

so it fits both interfaces, `TaskScheduler` and `TaskExecutor` (super type of `SchedulingTaskExecutor`).

If you try to inject a field of type `TaskExecutor` like your stack trace says

```
Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor...
```

Spring won't be able to choose which one.

This will only happen if the `ApplicationContext` from where you are trying to pull the beans has already initialized the beans, for example, in a Web application where your root context would register `MyConfiguration` and where the servlet context would declare your `screenerJobExecutor` bean that needs to be injected with a bean of type `TaskExecutor`.

You can indeed use

```
@Qualifier(value = "taskExecutor")
```

to fix this particular situation as Spring will use the bean name and not the bean type to satisfy the injection target.